# Setting up SMTP server (Windows 2008 R2) to use with Microsoft Data Protection Manager

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, smtp, scdpm, data-protection

DPM is installed on one of our servers - namely Datacenter. Essentially, there is no Exchange server in the domain, so we wanted to setup our own SMTP, and use a gMail account to forward reports/notifications from DPM elsewhere.

The problem is that DPM asks for an SMTP server, port, "from" address, which is all fine. It then asks for authentication for the SMTP server, a username and password of the person whose from address is mentioned above.

Now, it's probably quite a unique situation - but any ideas on how to go about setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be if you configure IIS to act as your SMTP server.  I have done this in the past with Server 2008.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e4cf06f5-9a36-474b-ba78-3f287a2b88f2.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

Gmail will allow you to send mail from a client (say Outlook).  (Google Gmail Outlook setup for more info)  It does require a secured connection to do so but you can probably just have it login to Gmail to send email from your server.  Rather than having to maintain and secure an SMTP virutal server on your windows box.